Showing that the capacity of $p_A=\prod_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nA_{ij}x_j$ is $1$
Let $A\in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^{n\times n}$ be a doubly stochastic matrix, and define the polynomial
$$p_A=\prod_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nA_{ij}x_j$$
I want to show that the capacity of $p_A$ is $1$, where the capacity is defined as follows:
$$\text{cap}(p):=\inf\left\{p(x):x\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}^n, \prod_{i=1}^nx_i=1\right\}$$
The hint I have is to use the AM-GM inequality.
Showing that $\text{cap}(p_A)\leq 1$ is rather easy (take $x=(1,1,\ldots,1)$). I am struggling to show the other direction. To complete the proof, I was trying to show that also $\text{cap}(p_A)\geq 1$. For I have tried doing the following. Take $x\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}^n$ such that $\prod_{i=1}^nx_i=1$:
$$p(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nA_{ij}x_j\geq\prod_{i=1}^n n\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^nA_{ij}x_j}=\prod_{i=1}^n n\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^nA_{ij}\prod_{i=1}^nx_j}=\prod_{i=1}^n n\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^nA_{ij}},$$
but then I'm stuck here. Another thing that I tried was assuming that $\text{cap}(p_A)<1$ and trying to reach a contradiction, but this also got me nowhere. Could someone help me conclude?
P.S. This is not a homework exercise, I am just going through some problems to prepare for my final exams :)

We can apply weighted version of the AM-GM inequality to each sum:
$$
\sum_j A_{ij} x_j \ge \left(\sum_j A_{ij}\right) \left( \prod_j x_j^{A_{ij}} \right)^{1/\sum_j A_{ij}} = \prod_j x_j^{A_{ij}}.
$$
Taking product over $i$ gives
$$
p_A(x) \ge \prod_{ij} x_j^{A_{ij}} = \prod _j x_j^{\sum_i A_{ij}} = \prod_j x_j =1.
$$
